# Shift key disabled using Windows 8 running in Virtualbox, with multiple monitors

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, multiple-monitors, shift

I have windows 8 installed in VirtualBox - running on linux.

I also have multiple monitors.

When I extend my display over both monitors, my shift key stops working.  I can still access capital letters using caps-lock, but cannot access certain symbols such as @, which require the shift key.

If I only use a single monitor, the shift key works fine.

Problem persists after a complete wipe and reinstall.

Any idea what could be causing this?  It would be really handy to be able to use both my monitors in Windows.

Comment: This sounds like a bug with Virtualbox itself.

Comment: I agree - but what I'm looking for is WHY this is happening, what is the connection between virtual keyboard and virtual monitor - so I can figure out a workaround.

Comment: Considering I am not a Virtualbox developer you might have better luck at the Virtualbox community forums, where you might catch somebody, familiar with the problem.